# Export emails and attachments to pdf

Tags: pdf, outlook

I am looking for suggestions on a software or an extension to work with Outlook, primarily to export emails with attachments (bulk exports of 50+ attachments).

Comment: Just wanted to update that we are using MessageExport, it isn't 100%, but it pulls the majority of attachments out of emails, and packages them in order with their parent email into a pdf.  Must have Adobe Pro and a computer with decent processing power to handle large bulk exports.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Export Messages to PDF](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/OutlookMessagesExportPDF) utility included in ReliefJet Essentials.

Answer (score 0):

It's expensive, but our office uses [PDFMaker](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/creating-pdfs-pdfmaker-windows.html#convert_email_messages_to_pdfs), a plugin for Microsoft Outlook that comes with Adobe Acrobat Standard (~$300) and Adobe Acrobat Professional (~$600).

- Convert from one email, multiple emails (Ctrl+click or Shift+click to select multiple messages), or an entire folder at once.
- Convert to one combined PDF, one PDF per email, or a PDF Portfolio.
- Auto-archive files as PDFs.